# Get values according function parameters in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the next function:

```js
const fun = (nr, car, color, obj) => {
  const cars = nr - 2;
  const colors = nr - 1;
  const objects = nr -3;
  const main = {
    c: `${cars}cars.`,
    co: `${colors}colors.`,
    obj: `${objects}objects.`
  };

  console.log(car && main.c, color && main.co, obj && main.obj)

  return `${car && main.c || color && main.co|| obj && main.obj}`;
};

console.log(fun(65, false, true, true))
```

How you can notice, depending by the parameters `fun(65, false, true, true)` i should get the correct data. In this example i should get this string `64colors. 62obj.`, but i don't get this. So depending by the parameters i want to show the corresponding values. How to do this?

Comment: How would you get two results on an OR  now you fixed the typo?

Comment: First of all it should be main.co, not main.colors

Comment: @36ve,  i changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using the or operator within the string, it just returns the result till a first non falsy value and not any further. You need to split your logic into three parts to be able to create a proper string

```js
const fun = (nr, car, color, obj) => {
  const cars = nr - 2;
  const colors = nr - 1;
  const objects = nr -3;
  const main = {
    c: `${cars}cars.`,
    co: `${colors}colors.`,
    obj: `${objects}objects.`
  };

  console.log(car && main.c, color && main.co, obj && main.obj)

  return `${car && main.c || ''}${color && main.co || ''}${obj && main.obj || ''}`;
};

console.log(fun(65, false, true, true))
```

Answer (score 1):

`main.colors` would return undefined which is falsy because it doesn't exist in the `main` object.

And the OR `||` operator doesn't return more than one value.

I changed the return statement so you can get `64colors62objects`

```js
const fun = (nr, car, color, obj) => {
  const cars = nr - 2;
  const colors = nr - 1;
  const objects = nr -3;
  const main = {
    c: `${cars}cars.`,
    co: `${colors}colors.`,
    obj: `${objects}objects.`
  };

  return `${car && main.c ? main.c : ''}${color && main.co ? main.co : ''}${obj && main.obj ? main.obj : ''}`;
};

console.log(fun(65, false, true, true))
```